# Question about piecewise smoothness of curves

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am interested to know whether all curves can be broken down into intervals somehow that they become piecewise smooth?

Or could someone give me an example of how a non-piecewise smooth curve would look like?

Comment: What about the curve $(t,f(t))$ where $f$ is the Weirstrass function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: Is $f$ is the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $(t,f(t))$ is a curve that is nowhere continuous, thus nowhere smooth.